# Отметить доступ к объекту как к массиву устаревшим

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Есть объект, реализующий `ArrayAcess` и его методы. Нужно отметить использование "магических" методов этого интерфейса `(offsetGet, offsetSet)` устаревшими `(@deprecated)` с выводом соответствующего варнинга. Варнинг хочется выводить как при простом вызове одного из этих методов(что довольно просто), так и при работе с объектом как с массивом (та самая "магия").

Comment: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/issues/1604

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348092/4804629